# Aligning child div to bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

Having trouble aligning the inner child div tag with the bottom of the parent div tag.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfFZG.png]

Html:

```
<div class="product_standard" >
    <div class="product_low" >

    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Got answered in the comments by ceejayoz:
on the parent style do:
position: relative
and on the child do:
position: absolute
bottom: 0
width: 100%

Comment: position: relative on product_standard and position: absolute, bottom: 0, width: 100% on product_low. Pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the help, could just not remember, I am not the best for css but I am for php script :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a Demo as per the image.

----Below is the CSS Code----

```
#main{background:url("http://lorempixel.com/500/500");
  width:500px;
 height:500px;
  position:relative;
  }
#main:after{
   content: "12.49 EURO";
  z-index:1;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  font-size:2em;
  color:#000000;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}
```

---HTML code look like ----

```
<div id="main"> </div>
```

Here is the Working Demo. http://jsbin.com/duhicoqo/1/

Comment: Posted Demo link work for you?

Comment: if the Demo link work for you may closed this answer by accepting the answer.